# Lazy evaluation of jsp elements

Tags: jsp

My situation: Page in JSP. I want change eg. title of result html in java  code below, eg. in `<body>`. I found that it is not possible in jsp technology: output is created top-down. I must move whole logic before injecting beans or jstl tags?

Comment: Learn about MVC. Your controller should have prepared all the data needed by the view before dispatching to that view. BTW, there is no "java code below" in your question.

Comment: Just forward to another jsp, of course if you don't like servlets to initialize some attribute for e.g. title.